# Nonlinear absorption coefficient and the band gap

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics, material-science, non-linear-optics

How does the nonlinear absorption coefficient depend on the band gap?
How can that coefficient be calculated theoretically? (Preferably with an example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two photon absorption is the nonlinear mechanism most sensitive to band gap, and it depends on the band gap being twice $\hbar \omega$ or smaller.  It can be estimated using standard second order perturbation theory.  See for example http://aristotle.sri.com/srini/73-JAP.pdf